# How did Jor El expect his son to use his powers in Superman 1-2?

Tags: superman

In the first movie (1978) Jor El told that it is forbidden to interviene into people's history. But in the second movie he was against his son letting go his powers.
First he tells not to use them, then he's against getting rid of them.

Comment: Perhaps you would clarify this. Jor-El is fine with his son *having* powers as long as he does not use them to change history. Not that this stops Superman from doing that.

Comment: @Paulie_D It reads to me like your comment only re-emphasizes the question.... if he doesn't want him to use the powers to change history, then what does he want him to use them for? If he doesn't want him to use them at all, then why be against him getting rid of them?

Comment: Every person has many abilities which they use for many purposeses.  But as far as Iknow nobody has ever used their abilitiees for the purpose of changing past history.  Jor-el could be in favor of Kal el using his powers in many ways which would affect or change the future history of Earth, while being agaist Kal el using his powers to change the past history of Earth.  The op seems to imagine that the only possible use of Superman's powers is to change past history.

Comment: @RS Hello! While I think your Q is good question, is there any way you could edit your answer to include quotes? Just to better establish that this what the character/narrative chose to do between films.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you misinterpreted what Jor-El said.

He was not telling Superman to not use his powers to affect events on earth. In fact he specifically wanted Superman to use his powers to help people.

What he was forbidding was for him to “interfere in human history”; as in altering the past. A clue to this interpretation is that Superman remembers him saying this as he is making the decision to reverse time to save Lois. He is specifically choosing to disobey that decree.

Comment: Thanks, though it seems it was a real voice, not memory. First, because Superman was confused at the moment, like he didn't expect this voice to appear. And second, because in the 2nd movie turned out that Jor-El wasn't completely dead, he was in some crystals, because when Superman needed his powers back, Jor-El basically said that it will kill him (Jor-El) completely.

Answer (score 3):

The question supposes that the only possible use of Superman's powers is to change the past, which is contradicted by the many other things he uses his superpowers for in *Superman I* and *Superman II*.

Every person has many abilities which they use for many purposes. But as far as I know nobody has ever used their abilities for the purpose of changing the past. Jor-El could be in favor of Kal-El using his powers in many ways which would affect or change the future history of Earth, while being against Kal-El using his powers to change the past history of Earth.

Just as many persons on Earth - including readers of this Stack Exchange - are in favor of themselves and other persons using their abilities for many purposes but opposed to people using their abilities for other purposes, it is perfectly plausible for Jor-El to be in favor of his son using his superpowers on Earth for some purposes and not for others.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, you misunderstood a couple of things.  Here's some information that may help clear things up as well as provide extra insight.

On the ride to Earth and after Clark enters the Fortress of Solitude for the first time, Jor-El tells Clark (Kal-El) that he is forbidden from interfere with human *history*, not human development or progress.  This is because Jor-El knew that his son may indeed be able to travel into the past and wanted to instill in him that it was not allowed.  I'm sure you can realize the consequences of doing so, so let's not get into that.  Also, Jor-El tells his son about the powers he will have and how he has them.  He never forbade Clark from using his powers overall, just from changing history.

Originally Lois wasn't supposed to die in the first movie, with the "interfering in human history" being saved for the second movie.  The first movie was supposed to end with the missile explosion freeing Zod and crew from the phantom zone, thus a cliffhanger leading to the second movie.  This was changed so that the first is a standalone movie, with the second retroactively attaching itself to the first.  If you watch the Donner Cut of Superman II, you'll see the missile explosion freeing them instead of a bomb explosion.  You'll also see Superman changing human history (reversing time like in the first movie).  I don't know if Donner was going to keep that part in the second movie or not, but since he wasn't allowed to finish the second movie originally, he was sort of locked into it since that's what he had already prepared before he got undeservedly booted out.

So, if Lois hadn't died in the first movie, he wouldn't have changed history to save her, and the changing of history thing would have made sense in the second movie.  Both movies were designed so that they could both be treated as one "super" extra long movie if you wanted to watch them back to back, with minimal interruption/disconnect between the two.  Something that becomes quite noticeable when you consider the events in Superman II (Zod from the first movie) and the Donner Cut (visuals similar to Superman, changing of history, Jor-El instead of his mother).

Also, from one of your comments, Jor-El isn't alive in the crystal.  Rather, it's a version of him.  It's like a part of his essence, but it's not his soul.  It contains his knowledge and some of his feelings, but those were essentially programmed into the crystal.  This is demonstrated when Clark is talking to Jor-El after his first night of doing good deeds.  Jor-El makes the comment of having anticipated that Clark might enjoy using his powers for good and responds with how he couldn't have possibly done so.  "As in, how were you able to program the crystal to be prepared to respond to this outcome?"  Also, Jor-El saying that he anticipated (past tense) that possibility, thus having programmed the crystal to be ready with wisdom/advice for him based on it.

In the first movie, there was some time (about a month) between when Jor-El first warned the council of the impending doom of Krypton and when his launched his son in the rocket towards Earth.  With as smart as Jor-El was, he was able to plan ahead and save his son, providing wisdom for various outcomes in his son's life.  Also providing the building blocks for the other crystals that provide knowledge that is also available to Clark (as seen in Superman II, either version).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).